# Showing an inequality of a complex exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

If $T>2$ and exist $p$ such that $2(p-1)\leq T<2p$ show that  $\int_{0}^{T}|e^{i n\pi t}|^2dx\leq p\int_{0}^{2}|e^{i n \pi t}|^2dt.$

Hint: Use 2-periodicity of $e^{i n\pi t}$

I have this: $\int_{0}^{T}|e^{i n \pi t}|^2dt\leq \int_{0}^{2p} |e^{i n \pi t}|^2dt=p\int_{0}^{2}|e^{i n\pi sp}|^2ds$  with the change $s=t/p$

Comment: Doesn't $\int_0^2 e^{in\pi t} \, dt$ equal zero?

Comment: Sorry. Now, I fixed it.

Comment: This is just silly; $|e^{in\pi t}|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I have it!
$\int_{0}^{2p} |e^{i n\pi it}|^2dt=\int_{0}^{2} |e^{i n\pi it}|^2dt+\cdots+ \int_{2(p-1)}^{2p} |e^{i n\pi it}|^2dt=p\int_{0}^{2p} |e^{i n\pi it}|^2dt$